# SpringBoot: HikariCP: leakDetectionThreshold returns always 0 regardless of set value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp

I have a simple SpringBoot Application and would like to investigate the issues related to DB connections. For this purpose, I've set `leakDetectionThreshold` in application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      leak-detection-threshold: 300000
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

and logging to debug:

```
logging:
  level:
    com:
      zaxxer:
        hikari: debug
```

And I see the following behaviour:

1. `HikariConfig` is initialised and correct value is passed to setter `public void setLeakDetectionThreshold(long leakDetectionThresholdMs)` <-- 300000
2. However, when `HikariPool` is initialised - `this.leakTaskFactory = new ProxyLeakTaskFactory(config.getLeakDetectionThreshold(), houseKeepingExecutorService);` <-- config.getLeakDetectionThreshold() is always 0
3. The same in `poolEntry.createProxyConnection(leakTaskFactory.schedule(poolEntry), now);`

```
   ProxyLeakTask schedule(final PoolEntry poolEntry)
   {
      return (leakDetectionThreshold == 0) ? ProxyLeakTask.NO_LEAK : scheduleNewTask(poolEntry); <-- leakDetectionThreshold is always 0
   }
```

So, maybe, someone can help with it? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot to configure the `DataSource` or are you building your own?

Comment: I'm delegating SpringBoot to configure DataSource, there is no custom bean.

Comment: Could you add the startup logging to your question? I suspect that there are some debug/warning messages indicating why it is set to 0.

Comment: Additionally please add the spring boot version and hikari version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)

The issue was quite simple:

```
2021-04-12 12:51:22.066  WARN 31701 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - leakDetectionThreshold is less than 2000ms or more than maxLifetime, disabling it.
```